# @PreAuthorize is not working. What could be the problems?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

There is an admin page over which I have used `@PreAuthorize` annotation for role `ROLE_ADMIN`, however user without having this role can also access this page.

This security context file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" />

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/login"
        access="permitAll" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/admin"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') and over18" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/app/login"
        default-target-url="/app/base/" always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/app/login?error=true" />

    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        logout-success-url="/app/logout" />

    <security:access-denied-handler
        error-page="/app/User/error/403" />

    <security:remember-me key="webapp-key" />
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</security:http>


<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

and the controller is :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping
public String showAdminPage(){
    return "adminPage";
}
}
```

EDIT:

```
flag
```

I added code to checkout the user and the granted authorities and then I printed them out. This is the output

```
*************************************** [ROLE_USER] uddeshya *************************************** for 

System.out.println("***************************************\n\n\n");  
System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext() 
.getAuthentication().getAuthorities()); 
System.out.println(principal.getName()); System.out.println("\n
\n\n***************************************");
```

Comment: Preauthorize checks the role ADMIN if the method is executed. Put a statement in the code to sysout the method call.

Comment: I added code to checkout the user and the granted authorities and then I printed them out. This is the output `***************************************



[ROLE_USER]
uddeshya



***************************************
` for `System.out.println("***************************************\n\n\n");
  
  System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .getAuthentication().getAuthorities());
  System.out.println(principal.getName());
  System.out.println("\n\n\n***************************************");`

Comment: The code must be in the question, don't paste a code to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use anotation-based method security in your Spring MVC controllers, you need to set the following in the `DispatcherServlet`'s context configuration file.

```
<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

It seems that you put it into different configuration file.